# convert spaghetti code to, Java 8 with streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have below code written in a nested for-loop. I am thinking to convert it into Java8 streams so that I can do parallel processing.

***Code*:**

```
List<String> students = Arrays.asList("student1", "student2", "student3");
List<String> portfolio = Arrays.asList("portfolio1", "portfolio2");
List<String> sections = Arrays.asList("portfolio1", "portfolio2");
List<String> result = null;

for(int i = 0 ; i < students.size(); i++) {
  for(int j = 0 ; j < portfolio.size(); j++) {
      result.add(portfolio.get(j).process(sections.get(j), students.get(i)));
  }
}
```

Please help!.

Comment: `portfolio.get(j)` return a String, and String doesn't have `process` can you elaborate please?

Comment: @OleV.V. - I have just added a sample, real data will be of 1500 items in students list.

Comment: @YCF_L - Yup, you are correct, I just wanted to add the sample snippet, not the actual code. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested for loop can be replaced by a `Stream` with `flatMap`:

```
List<String> result =
    students.stream()
            .flatMap(s -> IntStream.range(0,portfolio.size())
                                   .mapToObj(i -> portfolio.get(i).process(sections.get(i), s)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course, in order for this to work `portfolio` cannot be a `List<String>`, since `String` has no `process()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I manage the **j** pointer?

Comment: @mayank I actually eliminated the i index, so the i index in my answer has the same purpose of your j index.

Comment: Got it, but I am maintaining two indexes for : **portfolio & students, result.add(portfolio.get(j).process(sections.get(j), students.get(i)));**. I am maintaining **i** for **students** & **j** index for **portfolio & sections**.

Comment: @mayankbisht, Eran uses `i` for portfolios and sections, and the student comes from the flatMap mapping function param `s`. If you replaced your outer for loop by a forEach loop, it would look very similar to Eran's solution

Answer (score 0):

While converting for-loop into streams might be a good idea, using parallel streams not necessarily (see https://dzone.com/articles/think-twice-using-java-8). I would consider using reactive streams instead (RxJava, Project Reactor, etc.).